# Calling 3 different javascript functions from onclick doesn't work, executes only the first function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to call all three functions to the same form but only the first one showPassword seems to work. What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<form name="form1" action="#">  
Username: <input type='text' name='username'/>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="showPassword(); warning(input);isEmpty()"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
 function showPassword() {
         alert("Your password is " + document.forms["form1"]["password"].value )
    }
    function warning(input){
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(input.value.match(numbers))
        {
        alert('Data not recognized');
        }
        else
        {
        alert('OK');
        }
    } 
     function IsEmpty(){
        if(document.forms['form1'].username.value == "" || document.forms['form1'].password.value == "" )
        {
        alert("Data missing");
        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `warning(input);` -> `warning(this);`

Comment: What is "Input" which is passed to warning() ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the first function has an alert. so it would wait for user confirmation before it could execute other functions.. Try removing alerts. they should work.

Comment: but dont u think after responding to the alert, the rest of the functions should be executed ?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem that the OP is facing. Yes, having the alert will pause JS execution, but I gather that the problem is that even after the user dismisses the alert, the other functions do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Call only 1 JS function (a new one) and call these three from that single script. It will be easier to manage your code.

`warning(input)` is not valid, you can't pass the reference to an element like this. I'm not even sure what `input` should be in this case. You can select the form element in the script too (as you do in the other function).

Comment: I'm betting `input` is supposed to be the `input` element that is calling the function, so as @RobW suggested, it should probably be `this` instead.

Comment: The first sentence of the second paragraph is incorrect, you definitely *can* pass an argument in an inline event handler.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that is fine, but in this case `input` is probably what @Travesty3 wrote. However I'll rephrase it to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser's developer console. (In Firefox, Tools → Web Developer → Web Console.) It'll show you the error that's happening. I think something like this:

```
ReferenceError: input is not defined
```

It'll also show exactly what line of code caused the error. In this case, this line:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="showPassword(); warning(input);isEmpty()"/>
```

Here's the bug. In your code, where it says `warning(input);`, JavaScript doesn't know what you mean by `input`; there's no variable with that name.

I'm not sure what you mean either. Do you want the `warning()` function to check the `username` input? the `password` input? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

call second,third functions in the body of 1st function...